# JQuery insert properties

Tags: jquery

My knowledge JQuery very bas. How a i can insert some code in html tag

**Before:**

```
<a href="#">text</a>
```

**After:**

```
<a href="#" title="test" class="some-class">text</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are bunch of functions - from `prop` to `addClass`. Read jquery manual.

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: I need to insert in <a> this line: name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" id="make-order" and write: $('#msProduct').find('a.as_trigger').prop(' name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" id="make-order"'); No changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways (see jQuery documentation) to modify different attributes.  You can add any attribute with

```
$('#item').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
```

or multiple items by passing it an object:

```
$('#item').attr({
    href: 'http://www.google.com',
    class: 'some-class',
    title: 'test'
});
```

You can learn more in the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use `addClass()` for adding a class and `attr("title","value")` for title attribute.